# What is max speed of WiFi Direct (P2P)?

Tags: protocol-theory, ieee-802.11, bandwidth, speed, throughput

I'm looking for information on what kind of speeds theoretically can devices connected through WiFI Direct achieve, assuming all devices support WiFi ac?

Comment: @Cown why did you delete your answer? It was great and I was still reading it...

Comment: Sorry i was unable to answer what Ylearn asked in the comments, why or how i got the results of the theoretical and actual test results. The source i was using did not specify any source of how they got those results, so i didn't think it was a good answer, since anyone could write those results.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal rates for WiFi direct (or an IBSS essentially) theoretically shouldn't be anymore different than from the regular infrastructure BSS case (Access Point based). Based on the SINR that you can achieve, and the number of available channels, you can accordingly select a suitable MCS and find the corresponding rates - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac#Data_rates_and_speed . You can find more details in the IEEE standard of course - https://standards.ieee.org/standard/802_11ac-2013.html

Comment: An IBSS does not provide performance anywhere close to infrastructure mode as members of the IBSS must broadcast their data with all the limitations of 802.11 broadcast. Additionally, WiFi Direct is closer to infrastructure mode than it is to IBSS in how it operates.

Comment: I'm familiar with the IEEE standard and MCS, my question is precisely about how Wifi Direct performance compares to ordinary setup with an AP, and how does it degrade with more P2P devices. @YLearn, could you elaborate?

Comment: @kar, unfortunately, I have been too busy of late to research enough to give a proper answer at this time. While I know quite a bit about 802.11, WiFi Direct is one of the areas I don't recall enough about as I mostly deal with Enterprise deployments and WiFi Direct tends to be more consumer oriented. I simply don't come across it enough to keep details fresh in my mind. Maybe I can circle back to this at some point when I have more time.